# How to use Mapsui 2.0.1 with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mapsui

As far as I understand we could use Mapsui in Xamarin.Forms starting from Mapsui 2.0 version.

Currently, the Mapsui version is 2.0.1, and Xamarin.Forms is 4.6.

I was looking for a simple example or tutorial that could guide me on how to add a Mapsui map to my Xamarin.Forms. All the examples I found are using the old Mapsui 1.4 version with Xamarin PCL projects.

Could anyone give me some direction on how to start with Mapsui 2.0.1 and Xamarin.Form 4.6?

Comment: Have you ever checked the guide of v2.0 upgrade :http://mapsui.com/documentation/v2.0-upgrade-guide.html ? BTW , why don't you use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/ or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/maps-api ?

Comment: Yes, I checked the upgrade guide, I didn't find something to start with. My client want to use OSM because he is afraid of google charged amount.

Comment: I still recommend you to take a look at [Xamarin.Forms Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/) , it supports almost of the features and pretty easy to use , it is for free also .

Comment: As far as I understand, Xamarin.Forms.Map will launch the default map application in your phone. If you don't have one in your phone, I think the app will be stack. if the default one is GoogleMap then you still need to pay for it if reach 1000 request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs were recently updated. See the Mapsui for Xamarin.Forms getting started here:

https://mapsui.com/documentation/getting-started-xamarin-forms.html